# Обращение к основному потоку в python threading

Tags: многопоточность, flask, python-3.6

У меня есть два потока python threading. В одном живет асинхронная функция (ей нет альтернативы из-за специфики api, с которой она работает), в другом Flask приложение. В момент, когда первый поток получает сообщение я хочу вызвать специальную функцию-обработчик во втором. Как именно я могу взывать функцию именно в основном(Flask) потоке ? 
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте объекты [Event](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects) для уведомлений между потоками

А для передачи данных между потоками - используйте [Queues](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#module-queue) и [Locks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects):

Алгоритм такой:

- Поток имеет некие данные для передачи другому потоку
- Запрашивает и получает Lock на работу с Queue
- Ставит данные в Queue
- Освобождает Lock
- Отправляет Event, что данные готовы
- Второй поток по приеме Event'a запрашивает и получает Lock на работу с Queue
- Забирает данные из Queue
- Освобождает Lock
- Обрабатывает данные